# Postgres aggregation function for jsonb

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

i want to aggregate postgres data, but i need where one query where i can use **aggregate function for different datatype**.
Basically want to combine this two queries.

```
select browser_id, jsonb_object_agg(key, val)
from (
    select browser_id, key, sum(value::numeric) val
    from aggregated_browser_days, jsonb_each_text(geo_city)
    group by browser_id, key
    ) s
group by browser_id;

select browser_id, sum(pageviews) as total_pageviews,
       STRING_AGG(DISTINCT browser_family, ',') AS browser, 
       STRING_AGG(DISTINCT device_model, ',') AS device_model,
       SUM(timespent) as total_timespent, SUM(sessions) as session_count
from data
GROUP BY browser_id
```

Can anyone please guide me??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data is coming from two different tables.  So a `JOIN` seems like the right approach.  Just in case the base tables contain different sets of browsers, I am suggesting a `FULL JOIN`:

```
select *
from (select browser_id, jsonb_object_agg(key, val)
      from (select browser_id, key, sum(value::numeric) as val
            from aggregated_browser_days cross join lateral
                 jsonb_each_text(geo_city)
            group by browser_id, key
           ) s
      group by browser_id
     ) bd full join
     (select browser_id, sum(pageviews) as total_pageviews,
             STRING_AGG(DISTINCT browser_family, ',') AS browser, 
             STRING_AGG(DISTINCT device_model, ',') AS device_model,
             SUM(timespent) as total_timespent, SUM(sessions) as session_count
      from data
      group by browser_id
     ) b
     using (browser_id)
```